# bring-up issues with FreeBSD 11.4 version

Tags: kernel-panic, custom-errors

Kernel Version 11.2  --  “Fatal double fault” error panic
Kernel Version 11.4  --  “Fatal double fault” error panic
Kernel Version 12.4  --  “Fatal double fault” error panic
Kernel version  13.0  --  “Fatal double fault” error panic

I have tried BIOS reset to factory settings like enabling speed steps and all but still no success. Happy to take any suggestion to try if any